# PHP struggling under heavy load - "failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)"

Tags: php, php-fpm

We're running a server with this software:
- Plesk 12.5
- Apache 2.4.6
- nginx 1.11.1
- PHP 5.6
- Centos 6
- MySQL (MariaDB) 5.5.60

We've noticed that PHP repeatedly gives this error when our server is under heavy load. We've experienced this during peak live traffic, and also load testing on a clone of the server.

In /var/log/plesk-php56-fpm/error.log:

```
[07-May-2020 05:45:20] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
[07-May-2020 05:45:21] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
[07-May-2020 05:45:21] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
[07-May-2020 05:45:21] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
[07-May-2020 05:45:21] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
[07-May-2020 05:45:21] ERROR: failed to prepare the stderr pipe: Too many open files (24)
```

When we see these errors, we get a lot of 504 Gateway Timeouts.

We can see that PHP processes have a file limit of 1024, which seems too low (we've increased it for MySQL/Apache/Nginx, but can't figure out how to increase it for PHP):

In /proc/{php_process}/limits:

```
Max open files 1024 4096 files
```

We can't figure out how to increase this.

```
# ulimit -n
65535
```

In /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

In /proc/sys/fs/file-max:

```
250000
```

In /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
fs.file-max = 250000
```

We've restarted the server after making those changes.

Any suggestions for increasing PHP's max open files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rlimit_files` parameter in the `php-fpm.conf` files needs to be adjusted:

```
rlimit_files = 4096
```

The path to the `php-fpm.conf` should be something like `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf`

Comment: Cheers - this worked
In this case, I had to update /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php-fpm.conf, then restarted PHP through Plesk